# Integrating tiny-lr in gulp-live-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-livereload

I'm using the node module [gulp-live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-live-server) to run an express app at `app.js`. It works, but the browser doesn't live reload. Near the bottom of the page in the link above the docs say that one must use the `tiny-lr` mod to integrate live reload. I looked all over and can't find how I am specifically supposed to add `tiny-lr`. I added the script tag as asked in my html file. Here's the `gulpfile`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gls = require('gulp-live-server');
var tinylr = require('tiny-lr');

var port = 35729;

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    var server = gls.new('app.js');
    server.start();

    tinylr().listen(port, function() {
      console.log('... Listening on %s ...', port);
    })
});
```

app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.get('/style.css', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/style.css');
});

http.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I did notice that while express is listening on port `3000`, tiny-lr is listening on `35729`. If I change the express port to `35729`, though, it throws and error and says there is already a server listening on that port. Any help is appreciated, thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need gulp task for this you can specify it in app.js file.

In app.J's file.

`var tinylr  = require('tiny-lr');
app.use (tinylr.middleware({ app: app }))`

Also the port should be 35729